# How to use the URL parameter of Three20 to launch the email client with an email address

Tags: iphone, xcode, email, url, three20

In a TTTableViewController I am displaying an URL and an Email address. I thought that just putting them in the URL: parameter of the TTTableMessageItem would launch the webbrowser and the email client but it does not.

Is there an easy way to do this with Three20 or do I need to code a specific function for that?

Thanks for your lights!

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying in your TTURLMap that you want the given url parameter to go to the TTWebController?  In my code, I use the following line of code so that any mappings I don't specify go to TTWebController:

`[TTNavigator navigator].URLMap from:@"*" toSharedViewController:[TTWebController class]];`

(apologies if the syntax isn't exactly right, I don't have the code with me)

Links:

http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_u_r_l_map.php
http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_web_controller.php